# How do I find MS word activeX server binaries and register them?

Tags: c++, qt, activex, binaries

I am using MS word activeX in my Qt application but it failing to load the documents on some machines running XP.The doc has pointed out that the problem might be related to this:

> Note however that the ActiveX server binaries you are using might not be installed on the target system, so you have to ship them with your package and register them during the installation process of your application.

[link to the Qt doc](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/activeqt-container.html)

TMy problem is where do I find those server binaries and how do I register them?I would appreciate good pointers on how to get this done.

Answer (score 0):

The passage you cite from Qt documentation only applies if you have the rights to redistribute the ActiveX server you're trying to use. This is common sense, really.

To use the MS Word ActiveX server, the target system must have a copy of MS Word installed. That's all there's to it.